# Represent newline character from Javascript to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using Javascript to build a string from an array and pass that to an HTML modal, however I am unclear as to how to display the string with line breaks in between, as now the HTML is representing the built string in Javascript as a single line. Any help would be appreciated.

Javascript:

```
    function ShowCrashString(str) {
    var temp_split = str.split(';');
    temp_str = '';

    for (var i=0; i < temp_split.length; i++) {
        temp_str += temp_split[i] + '\n;'
    }
    document.getElementById("crash-modal").innerHTML = temp_str;
}
```

HTML Modal Code:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Crash Analysis</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" id="crash-modal">

                            <!-- data gets populated here -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer" id="to-copy">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                                id="closeModal">Close</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="CopyToClipboard('crash-modal')">Copy</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `temp_str += temp_split[i] + "<br>"`. Since it is HTML, use `<br>` tag to break a line instead of `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<br/>` instead `\n` for HTML

```
temp_str += temp_split[i] + '<br/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you could do this:

1. Put your text in a <pre> tag. This will show your newlines
2. Use str.replace(/\n/g,"<br>") to replace your newlines with <br /> tags

Answer (score 0):

I think that will solve your problem

```
function ShowCrashString(str) {
    var temp_split = str.split(';');
    temp_str = '';

    for (var i=0; i < temp_split.length; i++) {
        temp_str += temp_split[i] + '<br/>'
    }
   document.getElementById("crash-modal").innerHTML = temp_str;
}
```